# Can an Integral Domain be considered a Vector Space?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $D$ is an integral domain that contains a field $F$. Can $D$ be considered a Vector Space over $F$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $D$ contains $F$ as a subring then yes, it is absolutely an $F$ vector space. It is an abelian group under addition and is closed under multiplication by $F$. All the axioms of vector space like distributivity come from $F \subseteq D$ being a subring. More specifically, we say that $D$ is an $F$ algebra, meaning that it has the structure of an $F$ vector space and a ring in a compatible way.

Answer (score 0):

For a vector space $(V,+)$ should be an abelian group. Your integral domain is a ring. With respect to the first operation $+$ if that is abelian then you can certainly form a vector space

Comment: I think it goes without saying that addition in a ring forms an abelian group.

Comment: Yes thats true but I wanted the OP to enquire whether this holds or not always.